# vue.js $emit custom event not working

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I am new to vue.js (2). I am writing vanilla JS.

When I try to use a custom event (close) I get a syntax error of ", expected" and ": expected". What I want is to add a custom close event to a component in the view. Then, in the template of the component I try to have the click event reach the custom close event. It is not working..

HTML

```
<div id="root" class="container">
    <bulma-modal v-if="showBulmaModal" @close="showBulmaModal = false"></bulma-modal>
    <button @click="showBulmaModal = true" class="button">Show modal</button>
</div>
```

JS

```
Vue.component('bulma-modal', {
    template: '<div class="modal is-active"><div class="modal-background"></div><div class="modal-content"><div class="box"><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p></div></div><button class="modal-close" @click="$emit('close')"></button></div>'
});

new Vue({
    el: '#root',
    data: {
        showBulmaModal: false
    }
});
```

Is there something I can't see or I am doing wrong? I can't get it right..

Comment: Your `bulma-modal` template uses single quotes around `close` which ends the template at the first one. Try `$emit(\'close\')`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to escape the single quotes you use inside your template.

```
template: '<div class="modal is-active"><div class="modal-background"></div><div class="modal-content"><div class="box"><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p></div></div><button class="modal-close" @click="$emit(\'close\')">Close</button></div>'
```

Here is your code [working](http://codepen.io/Kradek/pen/gmKVyM?editors=1010).